# Css scaling differently

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scaling

So I've been cycling around with html and css, and I can't seem to get around an issue with css scaling differently across browsers, I want to merge three divs together but somehow it seems to work in samsungs default browser but when I move over to chrome mobile, it scales differently.
Here's an example screen shot[samsungs default browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9lkM.jpg)

While here's the chrome's image:[chrome mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9DmB.jpg)

Here's my css:

```
div.topleft {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 8em;
  height: 10em;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
div.topcenter {
  position: fixed;
  left: 8.4em;
  top: 0;
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 8.5em;
  height: 10em;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
div.topright {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 8em;
  height: 10em;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
```

Thanks for any fixes and suggestions.

Comment: It looks like one of the browsers has a different scaling applied to the site (the border looks different despite being sized in pixels) the reason could be that this is changed in the browser or a missing or incorrectly setup`<meta name="viewport" ...>`. Despite that it could a different font size might also be a problem because `rem` and `em` depend on that. Anyways using `position` with `fixed` to make multiple elements side by side is the wrong approach use `display` with `flex` instead.

Comment: Damn thanks alot, will try!